# How to connect to a Postgres on Docker using java.sql package?

Tags: java, postgresql, docker

How do I connect to a PostgreSQL database (inside a Docker container) using `java.sql.` module?

I'm already running Postgres and accessing it using pgadmin with this config:

```
version: '3'

services:
  teste-postgres-compose:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "Postgres2019!"
    ports:
      - "15432:5432"
    volumes:
      - /home/renatogroffe/Desenvolvimento/Docker-Compose/PostgreSQL:/var/lib/postgresql/data 
    networks:
      - postgres-compose-network

  teste-pgadmin-compose:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: "admin@admin.com.br"
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: "PgAdmin2019!"
    ports:
      - "16543:80"
    depends_on:
      - teste-postgres-compose
    networks:
      - postgres-compose-network

networks: 
  postgres-compose-network:
    driver: bridge
```

But if I try to connect through my Java app I get the error:

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed.

This is the connection that I'm trying to call:

```
try{
    Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");            
    connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://teste-postgres-compose:15432/postgres", "postgres", "Postgres2019!");
} catch(ClassNotFoundException erro1){
    throw new RuntimeException(erro1);
} catch (SQLException erro2) {
    throw new RuntimeException(erro2);
}

return connection;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found 2 mistypes in your configuration

```
services:
  teste-postgres-compose:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "Postgres2019!"
    ports:
      - "15432:5432"
```

```java
connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://test-postgres-compose:5432/postgres", "postgres", "Postgres2019!");
```

1. Your service has name `teste-postgres-compose` but you connect to `test-postgres-compose`
2. `- "15432:5432"` you've exposed port `15432` but connect to `5432`

**Update:**

Sorry, my mistake. Of course the second container is pgadmin, not your application.

The containers' names like `teste-postgres-compose` are available just in `postgres-compose-network` network and may be used just other by other containers in same network. Applications are launched locally (I guess you launched java code from your IDE) may use just exposed ports with localhost. Services' names are not available outside the network.

For example your postgres has to be available by address:

> localhost:15432

Because you've exposed this port in the compose file. Also you may try loopback `127.0.0.1` or your host ip address.

Comment: sorry about that, i may have written wrong.
i'm using `conexao = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://teste-postgres-compose:15432/postgres", "postgres", "Postgres2019!");` and still got the same error.